# How to create empty IDB file with IDApython?

Tags: ida, idapython, automation

Is it possible to create empty idb file using idapython?

My intention is to use it afterwards to populate with several binary code blobs and run some analysis on the resulting idb file and all this using idapython.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is no API for creating an empty IDB. However, you can use the command line switches to start IDA with an empty IDB like so:

```
idaq.exe -t -p<ProcessorName> <IdbPath>
```

This will launch IDA with a new, empty IDB.